# Using RewriteRule in .htaccess for POST request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to lock down a page to only accept POST requests. as part of an RESTful API. I have the following, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^api/(call1|call2|call3)/?/ http://www.example.com/api/rest_services.php?_call=$1 [L]
```

Comment: How is it not working? Specifically, does it block nothing, or everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. Syntax error on the RewriteRule. Should be the following. Note the **$** not **/**

```
RewriteRule ^api/(call1|call2|call3)/?$ http://www.example.com/api/rest_services.php?_call=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to invert the condition to just match requests that are not POST:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^api/(call1|call2|call3)/?/ - [L,R=405]
```

And then you should also send the [405 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6) to tell the client the reason. But the `R=405` flag is only available since Apache 2. For Apache 1 you can send those requests to a PHP script that responds with that status code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not qualified to answer the question about `.htaccess`, but this is the way I'd rather do it anyway:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    die('some meaningful REST style error here');
}
```

Comment: yes. your users will be much happier and less mystified if you have an error message.

Comment: Thanks, and agreed. But there are other factors that back a RewriteRule solution. Plus, it's a mission now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in conjunction with `<Location>`:

```
<Limit GET>
  Deny from all
</Limit>
```