# prevent brower access to a form handler php file

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, permissions, shared-hosting

i know this has been answered lots on SO but i still have a question - i am using the cforms plugin in Wordpress and i've given it the url of a form handler page and i want to block direct access to this allowing only cforms - i've tried everything i've come across including file permissions and putting the file outside the root though everything that blocks the file to direct access also seems to block it from cforms ..... so i assume they're reading it as a browser would .... so i figure i'll need to block it from everybody except requests coming from my webserver (using htacesss) ..... but i am on a shared server and i dont want to leave it open to attack from the other domains on i share with .... so my question is this - can i target my domain specifically in htaccess using "allow" ?

thanks

ps this is my first time on SO so apologies if i havent searched hard enough etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since forms (and therefor also cforms) are submitted via a browser, you can't completely block browser requests to those files.

What you could do however is block requests that are not `POST` requests, since forms are normally posted. You can check in `.htaccess` if the request is a `POST` request, see
[Using RewriteRule in .htaccess for POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067393/using-rewriterule-in-htaccess-for-post-request)

Comment: thanks, that put me on the right track - i ended up using the php version [ if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    die('some meaningful REST style error here');
} ]