# How to secure a php file

Tags: php

I did a payment gateway integration on an existing website. The payment gateway gave me an API which I used and did the coding and stored it in a php file `pay.php`

I have a checkout form in the main website and on clicking submit, it sends all the needed data to `pay.php` via `post` and then this file does the rest and sends the data over to the payment gateway.

Since this `pay.php` file stores sensetive data, I want to secure it so that no one else can access it via web brwoser like entering `http://domain.com/pay.php` or be able to download it.

Now while I know that normally you can't just download `.php` files, I saw a site the other day which was capable of downloading my wordpress blog along with the `.php` files.

Also every time the `pay.php` file is run a payment link is generated, so  I need to make sure only the website `http://www.domain.com` is able to use this file and no 3rd party.

I already have a few ideas in my head like limiting access using remote IP and such but would want to know the best possible way to address the issue.

Comment: Since `pay.php` expects to receive a POST, you can't prevent the browser from being able to access it. You can make sure that it sends an error if not all the needed POST data is present (like some valid token or session info).  While it is possible to check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to be sure it came from the expected form, that is not at all reliable and will break for probably more users than it prevents from incorrect access.

Comment: When using PHP noone can see or download your code via web browser. As long as your PHP file is stored in a server with PHP enabled you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: It is possible to limit to POST with url rewriting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335231/prevent-brower-access-to-a-form-handler-php-file

Comment: A possible solution is to store the sensitive data in a different file `secure.php` and give it `700` access rights. Then include it in `pay.php`.

Comment: This has been asked a few times before. [Look through this search and similar searches...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+prevent++external+post)

Comment: If something is downloading your wordpress blog, it must be using an API specifically designed to allow managing the content. Any such interface should be protected by a password and/or secure certificate. There's nothing you can do about someone breaking into a server -- if you can upload/download the PHP script, so can someone else who guesses your password.

Comment: The typical approach to this problem is to store your PHP files outside your web server's document root and then have your autoloader include them as needed. This way, PHP files can only ever be accessed by running PHP code, and not by direct request from the web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the answer of Commusoft and to give a slight alternative.

This piece of `.htaccess` denies php file requests via the browser and makes sure you can only include the file from a different php file.

```
<Files *.php>
Deny from All
</Files>
```

Put this in a separate directory where `pay.php` is located.

I think the best way of dealing with this payment issue is to turn the `pay.php` into a full class and use it object oriented. That way you can use the functionality in any location and pass variables to it easily.

Comment: This is useless as it just blocks ALL PHP files from being accessed, clearly something you would never do.

Comment: @SJacks not sure why you are commenting on an answer from 2015 and also one which specifically mentions putting the file in a seperate directory.

Comment: Does it matter when the comment is made? People will see this and may include it in their HTACCESS file and if they do, they will block all access to PHP files. In virtually all circumstances this is not a desire and it should be explained that this will happen.

Comment: No, that's not the case. You are providing code without an explanation of what it does. I can't imagine anyone wanting to deny access to all PHP files on their server. That's what your code does.

Comment: I don't need to for the reasons already stated. You should edit your response to notify people of what will happen if they include your code in their htaccess file, or edit the code to target a specific file by replacing the asterisk :)

Answer (score 2):

- If you configure your webserver (Apache,...) correctly, the webserver will *render* the PHP so no one will ever have the opportunity to **see the file's source code**. So there is some *inherent protection*. But needless to say, it can be *hacked*.
- Now hackers of course wish to *hack* the website. And you **don't** have any contol on what data will be posted: that's up to the browser. Hackers sometimes **modify** the content before they send the request in the hope that the PHP script will fail somehow and reveal for instance SQL queries, etc. The first thing you thus better do is **turn off error reporting**:

  ```
  error_reporting(0);
  ```

  Since hackers can find some warnings/errors most helpful to figure out the underlying algorithm and corrupt it. By doing this explicitly in the PHP file, you prevent that if you modify the settings of the server, all of a sudden errors reappear.
- You furthermore better make sure a user has no direct access to the sensitive data anyhow. This can be achieved by **putting the sensitive data into a separate file** (say `secure.php`) and `include_once()` it so you can read it's data.
- As @Havenard and @AlexHowansky say, you can also store such files (`secure.php`) better **outside the publicly accessible directories**. For instance above `public_html`. This does not always fully resolves the problem because some webservers are sensitive to *URL-injection* (by specifying `http://www.domain.com/../securefolder/secure.php`, you can sometimes access a file above the publicly available directory).
- As @TomKriek says, you can also provide additiona protection to the "secure folder" by inserting a `.htaccess` file that contains the following lines:

  ```
  <Files *.php>
  Deny from All
  </Files>
  ```

  It means that the webserver - again if configured correctly - will prevent the users access from all `.php` files in the directory.
- Finally, you better give the files **proper permissions**: if the PHP engine runs as the same user as the owner of the files, you can give it `600` **access rights** (`chmod 600 secure.php`) or `640` in case the PHP engine runs on a different user than the owner of the file, but in the same user group, or worst-case `644` so that a hacker *can't modify* the file (or is at least not supposed to). You can also change the owner of the file to the `www-data` by running `chown www-data secure.php` so that the owner is the webserver and you can thus make the permissions more tight. The rule of thumb is always to *give it the least access rights to do its job correctly*.
- You can also make the files **read-only** once they are implemented by setting the rights to `400`, `440` or worst-case `444`. In that case at least a hacker can't enter his/her own bank account as the receiver of the payment ;).

To conclude, when designing/implementing a secure server, one better uses a *layered* approach where several measures are taken so that if one measure might fail, others hopefully will still prevent a hacker from accessing the server/files.

Comment: Access right won't prevent the server from reading the file and transmitting it to the user, as the server accesses the file using the same rights as the PHP scripts. If you want to prevent a file from being read in case of misconfiguration, you must store it outside the published folder.

Comment: @Havenard: actually they **do** prevent it being transmitted to a user (given of course the server is again configured correctly), you can test this yourself (by protecting a `.txt` file or something). Not to the PHP engine, since such engine normally runs with a different user.

Comment: It is not logical, and even if you are correct you are again relying on the server being configured correctly.

Comment: @Havenard: it's definitely logical, that's the whole point why todays servers are still multi-user. It's the first hint when you write a web application: use a different user so that even if they got access, they can't modify all data. And your suggested approach can also fail badly: if *Apache* is configured incorrectly, I can still access it by `http://domain.com/../hidden.php` by exploiting `..` as parent directory. You **always** will need to rely on the fact that the webserver processes requests somehow correctly.

Comment: @Havenard: this is also a way to get access to a unsecured server: you for instance upload a file with filename `../../../../etc/passwd`. And if the webserver is that stupid, it overrides the password file, and of course you injected your own password and thus have modified the lock so it only accepts your keys. And the way to prevent this from happening is securing `/etc` such that no user but the root can access it.

Comment: Setting perms 700 can only have an impact if you're running a non-embedded PHP (like nginx with FCGI), and the web service runs as a different user than the PHP service, and the PHP file is owned by the PHP service user. And even in this case, a user can still just directly hit the URL that triggers the include.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: no, if you try this with the permissions set on a webserver, you will see the webserver gives a `403 Forbidden` on files that don't have the propper permissions.

Comment: @Havenard I had already thought of implimenting that, but will this work in my case as this `pay.php` file needs to communicate with the payment gateway API will keeping it outside the `public_html` allow it to do that?

Comment: @RickRoy Where you run the script from doesn't affect what it can communicate with.

Comment: You can't require_once a file that the web server doesn't have permission to read.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: the webserver has permission, you can use an `include_once`, note that a webserver usually runs with root access, because accessing port `80` is by default not allowed. But the (more than) default behavior of a webserver is to respect permissions, especially when it comes down to users.

Comment: If the web server has permission to read a file, then it can serve that file to a client.

Comment: ^ And last I checked a PHP file can only have permission to read a file if the server that ran it also does. Thats why I don't find this assumption that you can fix the problem by setting permissions logical.

Comment: @Havenard: well a specified before, a webserver **needs** root access, how else can you let the server listen to port `80`.

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes but it doesn't access the files as root, it will use the credentials of a lower user like `nobody` or `www-data`, and will run PHP scripts with the same permission.

Comment: It should *never* run as root. It starts as root, and then switches to an unprivileged account like www. Your files should then be owned by something other than www and chmod-ed so that www can read them.

Comment: Well in that case or you transfer the files to `www-data`; or you give it `770` access. But as an extra safety measure, even after shielding it in a separate directory, you can still use permissions. Because - as already argued - the webserver needs access to the file. And some hacks (like url injection) sometimes work. So you can combine the directory and permission protection.

Comment: When someones `post`s something to a URL, that url needs to be reachable, so you can't hide `pay.php` into a hidden folder, if the browser will need to `post` data to it.

Comment: Right, which is why it needs to be readable by the web service process, which means it can still be served by requesting it directly. Permissions required to execute the PHP as intended and permissions required to serve the file directly to a remote user ARE THE SAME. Which is why the proper solution has nothing to do with permissions, rather it's to put the file outside DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: Permissions on the file only come into play if you're concerned about local users or running a CGI PHP in a separate process.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: if you give a file (for instance `foo.txt`, `777` rights, the user can see it, if you give it `770` files, one gets a `403`, but you can still access it by PHP. Although (I edited the solution), moving the files outside the document root is a good solution, there is always a chance, one finds a way to circumvent this (or modify the .htaccess). In that case, you can hope that permissions give you some additional security. As always in security: only a layered approach works where different measures hope to help each other out if one fails.

Comment: `but you can still access it by PHP` Not if you have an embedded PHP. Apache and PHP run *as the same user*, so if you deny access to Apache, then you also deny access to PHP.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: well I rewrote it as giving it the *least access rights to do its job correctly*, so that should probably resolve the conflict. It's probably never a good idea to give more rights than strictly necessary in case of security anyway. I hope this resolves the "conflict".

Comment: Your files should not be writable to the user running the web service. *Never never never* run 700 or 770. chown them to a separate user and chmod them to 644 or 640 .

Comment: @AlexHowansky: true, a php file doesn't have to be excutable since the webserver runs it (not as a file, but using an interpreter). Modified it.

Comment: Not executable is irrelevant. Not writable is critical, so 600 is just as bad as 700.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: true, but that's only **after** the file is implemented and some IDE's modify the files on the webserver directly so they require write-access.

Comment: The issue isn't having write access in general, it's having write access by the user that the web server is running under. If your files are 600 then the files have to be owned by the same user the web server runs under, which means the web server can now overwrite them. You should never have web files chmod 600, they should be 644 or 640. (Or maybe even 444 or 440.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You may perform only POST requests in this file (also you have to validate even POST requests). GET request will return nothing or an error.
2. Usually you cannot download php file in easy way. There is should some holes in the security of the site to do this.
3. You may direct all request into the one php file. Usually it's index.php. Try to see how to configure it via `.htaccess`. And users will not know about your real PHP files.
4. You may protect your files via permissions if needed.

Comment: By redirecting all requests to `index.php` a problem might occur that if the file is leaked, all source code is made public. Separation of files thus has its merits.