# Is there a way redirect http requests based on whether its get or post?

Tags: php, http, http-redirect

I want to have an API such as mysite.com/CustomerIds, and be able to have GET and POST requests be redirected by the .httpaccess file to different php files. For eg. GETs would go to CustomerIds_get.php and POSTs would get redirected to CustomerIds_post.php.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067393/using-rewriterule-in-htaccess-for-post-request

Answer (score 0):

`.httpaccess` is webserver specific, it's not part of PHP. However it's simple enough to do in PHP, with the added benefit of keeping your code all in one place rather than relying on web server configuration.

```
CustomerIds.php

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    include("CustomerIds_post.php");
}
else
{
    include("CustomerIds_get.php");
}
```